# Stored Procedure for saving into two table

Tags: sql-server

I want to store the value of @Additional variable which i am getting from front end and which is in the format '98789797,879879879,987987978' . I want to store this in different columns of  table 'PhoneNo.s' by removing comma between two no.s for the same username.

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddNewEmployee]
    (       
    @Name   nvarchar(30),
    @SurName    nvarchar(20),
    @Email      nvarchar(30),   
    @Mobile nvarchar(60),
    @Address        nvarchar(65),
    @File nvarchar(40),
    @Country nvarchar(20),
    @State nvarchar(20),
    @City nvarchar(20),
    @Gender nvarchar(10),
    @Additional nvarchar(100)
    )
         AS
         begin
     insert into Users
      ( Name, SurName, Email, Mobile, Address,FilePath,Country,State,City,Gender)
     values
      (@Name, @SurName, @Email, @Mobile,@Address,@File,@Country,@State,@City,@Gender)
   insert into [PhoneNo.s]
      ( 
     UserId,PhoneNo)

     values
      (
    @Name,

    @Additional

     )

   end
```

How can i achieve this?? I am not that much pro in sql..It is looking very complex to me i can not proceed further!!

Comment: You are not declare variables name, Additional and assign values for that...

Comment: i have updated now , well!! But tell me how can i remove the comma s and insert into the different columns of [PhoneNo.s]Table?

Comment: Udf split function...

Comment: if i split the different no.s and insert them , they all get stored in one column only ,,but i want each phone no. must save in next column with same username

Comment: The question is tagged with MySQL, but this looks like SQL Server. Please can you clarify which it is? If it is SQL Server then I would strongly recommend using a [Table-Valued Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to store the numbers, instead of passing them as a delimited string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the split function.  This is working in sql server.  You can change this to mysql

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]  
(  
 @RowData nvarchar(MAX),
 @SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)    
 RETURNS @ReturnValue TABLE   
(Data NVARCHAR(MAX))   
AS
BEGIN
   Declare @Counter int
   Set @Counter = 1 
 While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)>0) 
 Begin  
  Insert Into @ReturnValue (data)  
 Select Data = 
  ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)))
  Set @RowData = 
  Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData)) 
 Set @Counter = @Counter + 1  
End 
Insert Into @ReturnValue (data)  
Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))  
Return  
END
```

Inside your stored procedure

Your first insert coding is correct.  Replace second insert coding to the below coding.

```
 DECLARE @PhoneNumber Varchar(MAX)
 SET @PhoneNumber='98798797,897987,9879'
 INSERT INTO AddnewEmployee(name,phonenumber)
 SELECT @name, Data FROM dbo.Split(@phonenumber,',').
```

The above code split the numbers and insert each row like

```
 name     phone number

 AJ       98798797
 AJ       897987
 AJ       9879
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @ProductNames  what is this?

Comment: it is ok for viewing !! But how can i insert into columns by splitting comma s between them

Comment: Split function takes care.... Actually it it working for insert...   I think you have two columns in phone.s table right? If so, you have to insert like peter 29999, john 44444, aryl 455555 right?  If the above logic is correct, it is going to work....

Comment: if my query is like this AddnewEmployee('Aj','98798797,897987,9879'), It should insert 3Aj usernames and in each username there should be one phone no. this is what i want to achieve

Comment: thanx vanarajan u helped a lot !!! I can achieve whatever i want with the help of ur code!!!!!!!!